# Is it permissible to play musical instruments on Eid?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, music, singing

### Question

Is it Permissible to Play musical instruments on Eid?

### Research Effort

The playing of Musical instruments in general, appears (to me) to be forbidden:

> Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari: that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers `there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful.` And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection." **[ [bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5590) ]**

---

However in my interpretation of this next Hadith, the messenger  permitted some girls to sing a song of the Ansar as an exception, because its Eid:

> Narrated Aisha: That once Abu Bakr came to her on the day of Id-ul-Fitr or Id ul Adha while the Prophet (ﷺ) was with her and there were two girl singers with her, singing songs of the Ansar about the day of Buath. Abu Bakr said twice.  "Musical instrument of Satan!" But the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an Id  and this day is our Id." **[ [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3931)]**

But Abu Bakr views the singing of these girls as a:

> "Musical instrument of Satan!"

So this formed the question for me, if Singing ( a song of the ansar about the day of buath) is allowed on Eid and Abu Bakr views that Singing as a kind of (satanic) Musical Instrument; (and the messenger did not correct him in that); then

**Is it Permissible to Play musical instruments on Eid?**